# Issues with applying Mixin dynamically - A-FRAME

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to figure out how I can use mixins as a sort of state.

But im running into an issue, when I have an element that already has a mixin and then try to update the mixin value of that element. It DOES change the mixin, but it doesnt change the properties from the old mixin to the new one

By default a element has the `makeitblue` mixin but after the timeout it gets the `makeitred` mixin.

but as you can see from the example, it does change the mixin but it doesnt change the element properies (I am also getting alot of empty properties).

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        AFRAME.registerComponent('test-element', {

            init: function () {

                let element = this.el;

                setTimeout(function(){
                    element.setAttribute('mixin', 'makeitred')
                }, 3000);

            },

        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <a-mixin id="makeitred" position="-2 0.5 -3"  material="color: red"></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="makeitblue" position="2 0.5 -3" material="color: blue"></a-mixin>
    </a-assets>
    <a-cylinder test-element mixin="makeitblue"></a-cylinder>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [entities and components](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html#sidebar) vs. primitives. Primitives are a learning tool and more advanced features like mixins are less tested and might still have [some bugs](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4717)

An example of what you are trying to accomplish using the equivalent entity / component expansion of the `a-cylinder` primitive:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/bold-celestial-windshield?path=index.html%3A26%3A20

Comment: im sorry as you know im still very new to this
primitives are just a pre made entities with pre set properties right?
I also dont get how it works on an entity but not on a cilinder, sorry :pensive:
like I get that primitives are just used so you can learn to use those entities, but once you 
understand them you should just use a geometry property to specify the primitive right?

"Primitives are a learning tool and more advanced features like mixins are less tested and might still have some bugs"
I dont get what you mean, are mixins primitive too?